# Xcode Server setup failed

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, osx-server

I'm trying to install Xcode Server, and getting the following error msg (after chooseing Xcode in the "choose Xcode" button) :

> **Xcode Server setup failed (starting api server)** Try clicking Xcode and
>   selecting a newer versino of Xcode

Machine:
Mac Mini (mid 2011), OS X Yosemite, 2.3GHz Intel Core i5, 4GB 1333MHz DDR3

Server:
Version 5.0.4 (15S2259)

Xcode:
Version 7.0 (7A220)

I have tried installing and deleting all components involved several times, but with no success.xc

Any help would be appreciated.

**[Update]**
Bug was submitted to Apple bug report, it's status is now closed.

Answer (score 2):

This one bit me during a server upgrade. Moving to El Capitan and Server 5.1.5.

Xcode refused to work telling me I needed to upgrade to the latest versions of Xcode and Server, which I was already using, error message as above.

The only way around it was to run

```
sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset
```

this solved the problem.

### HOWEVER!

Make sure you backup before you run it as it will get rid of everything associated with the Xcode server, including any repositories. Check in /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ for anything you need to save.

Comment: appreciate the extra info, though i believe that the hardware on the mac just wasn't sufficient.